# Sliding UP and DOWN Animation for my Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 2 LinearLayouts which splits the screen into two, Top and Bottom (Refer the screenshot). when the user press the the  FloatingActionButton ,the first LinearLayout should slides upwards and the second LinearLayout should slide downwards, here is my try, but its not working  ,  [image: see my concept]

this is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
tools:context="com.example.jaisonjoseph.sample.MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/first"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_weight=".1"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/second"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight=".1"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />


</LinearLayout>
```

these are the 2 xml files for animation

first one

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="100%" />
```

second

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<translate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromYDelta="100%"
    android:toYDelta="0" />
```

here is the code for main activity

```
   final LinearLayout first =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.first) ;
    final LinearLayout second =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.second) ;

    final Animation slide_down = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_down);
    final Animation slide_up = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_up);

   FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {





           first.setAnimation(slide_up);
           second.setAnimation(slide_down);

        }
    });
}
```

[image: after adding the answer]

Comment: `but its not working` can you specify what actually is not working?

Comment: when first.setAnimation(slide_up); and 
           second.setAnimation(slide_down); is on the onclik of FloatingActionButton ,its not animating .when i put those to codes in oncreate its animating now@rafsanahmad007

Comment: if i use a button instead of  FloatingActionButton , same problem there@rafsanahmad007

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `startAnimation()` instead of `setAnimation()`.

**Try this:**

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

       first.startAnimation(slide_up);
       second.startAnimation(slide_down);
    }
});
```

**slide_up.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<translate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="-200%" />
</set>
```

**slide_down.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<translate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="200%" />
</set>
```

Here is a good [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/) about different types of animation.

Hope this will help~

Comment: Ok that's working, can U suggest me the best animation (xml) to do this, the above animation is not fulfilling my concept (see my screenshot)..

Comment: for slide_up.xml `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >

    <scale
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.0" />
</set>`  this fits, can give slide_down code by making changes my code, and post the answer

Comment: just change  android:fromYScale="0.0" and android:toYScale="1.0" for slide down

Comment: thats not enough

Comment: check my comment.

Comment: just see my comment

Comment: take a look at my gif screenshot , its not dividing properly from the middle(where the floating button presents) , please edit your answer

Comment: Great brother, can we add animation listener to this?